# What does it take to overcome your  Goa'uld symbiote?

Tags: stargate, goauld

In the stargate universe, when an adult Goa'uld symbiote bonds with you it takes control over your body, forcing you to watch as it commits horrific deeds.

However Skaara manages to overwhelm his symbiote at some point at theend of one of the seasons. This is just one example though.

What does it take to overcome your symbiote, if you're bonded with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually people cannot overcome a symbiote.

You can only overcome one when either the **symbiote isn't that strong, probably bonded prematurely**(it was in the eariler episodes, on char i think) or **your will is too strong for the symbiote to control you.**  Or the use the Tollen device which was used to put Skaara/Symiote to trail.